# selenium ide vs katalon recorder

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, katalon-studio, rpa, katalon-recorder

From what I understand, katalon recorder(about 4MB) is lightweight selenium ide(about 15MB) alternative. I am trying to understand, why is there so much difference in size. Has katalon cut down on the number of features supported or it has implemented the code in a very efficient way or somewhere deep down it is using some ready made library?.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand, why is there so much difference in size.

Katalon Recorder and the new Selenium IDE started as clone from the same open-source project from Taiwan. But then they moved in different directions. SIDE added new features and a totally redesigned UI, using different libraries.